# MySQL data from foreign table

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know using which method I can get my data from MySQL, hence the title.

Anyway I have 2 tables `event_details` and `event_dates`. `event_details` has fields `id,name,created,modified`. Important table is `event_dates`. Which stores `start_date` and `end_date` of the events.

Sample data is like below

```
id    eventId    date
1       72       20160520
2       72       20160521
3       72       20160522
4       73       20160518
5       74       20160519
6       75       20160524
7       75       20160525
8       75       20160526
```

Here scenario for `startdate` and `enddate` is like this

1. If there is only 1 entry for `eventId` that means event has same `startDate` and `EndDate`.
2. If eventId is in the table for more than 2 times than first entry is `startDate` and last entry is `endDate`.

So I got confused that what method should I use to get result in one table with `startDate` and `endDate` of the event.

I want data in following format

```
Name          startDate     endDate
music show    20160520      20160522
racing show   20160518      20160518
pupet show    20160519      20160519
dance show    20160524      20160526
```

Let me know if it's easier through getting data in array in PHP file and than run through loops or easier using the MySQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    ed.id,
    ed.name,
    created,
    modified,
    min(startDate) start_date,
    max(endDate) end_date
FROM
    event_details ed
RIGHT JOIN event_dates edates ON ed.id = edates.id
GROUP BY    ed.id;
```

Comment: as `event_date` table should has multiple event_date for a particular event_id

Comment: i tried the query and it gave me minimum of date and maximum of date for whole table. Not for each event

Comment: Updated the query...missed to use `group by`

Comment: should i use `group by` using the `event_detail_dates` foreign id column because that table will have more than one entries for each `event`?

Comment: you need to use `group by` on `event_id`. It will not effect which table you use.

Comment: thank you very much. I think its working just need to double check the data.

Comment: If it solve your problem, the add this as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this :

```
SELECT t.id,MIN(t.date) as start_date,MAX(t.date) as end_date,t1.name
FROM t,t1
where t.id=t1.id
GROUP BY id
```